# How can get All Attribute of a specific Group in magento2

Tags: attributes, group

In constructor inject dependency

```
protected $productAttInterface;
\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeManagementInterface $productAttInterface

$this->productAttInterface=$productAttInterface;
```

and get all attributes of a specific **attribute set**

`$attributeSetId=16;`    //This is Attribute Set Id

```
return $this->productAttInterface->getAttributes($attributeSetId);
```

Now i want to get all attributes of a specific group . I make a group and add **5 attributes**. I want to just get these 5 attributes not all. 
Can anyone guide me how get attributes of specific group by giving  **group_name or group_id** ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code. It may be helpful for you :

```
protected $attributeGroupCollection;
protected $productAttributeCollection;

public function __construct(
    ..........
    \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory $attributeGroupCollection,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $productAttributeCollection
    ..........
)
{
    ..........
    $this->attributeGroupCollection = $attributeGroupCollection;
    $this->productAttributeCollection = $productAttributeCollection;
    ..........
}

public function yourFunction(){
    $attributeSetId = 4;
    // \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory
    $groupCollection = $this->attributeGroupCollection->create()
        ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
        ->load(); // product attribute group collection
    $attributeCollection = [];
    foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
        // \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory
        $groupAttributesCollection = $this->productAttributeCollection->create()
            ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())
            ->addVisibleFilter()
            ->load(); // product attribute collection

        foreach ($groupAttributesCollection->getItems() as $attribute) {
            if($attribute->getAttributeGroupId() == 14){
                $attributeCollection[] = $attribute->getData();
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($attributeCollection);
    exit;
}
```